# Expected and maximum likelihood estimate positions of particle in a box

Tags: brownian-motion

From [Causal Entropic Forces, A. D. Wissner-Grossand C. E. Freer, Physical Review Letters](http://www.alexwg.org/publications/PhysRevLett_110-168702.pdf)

Regarding a particle exhibiting brownian motion within a box...

> ...In contrast, if the particle had merely diffused from its given
>   initial state, while its expectation position would relax towards the
>   center of the box, its maximum likelihood position would remain
>   stationary.

My intuition here is that for as time progresses the expected and maximum likelihood positions both tend towards the centre of the box. And for small t they are both nearer the starting point.

That is, after a long period of time the particle will have been restricted from moving beyond the boxes bounds many times such that the bias it has towards the starting position is decayed - towards the centre of the box.

So how is it that the maximum likelihood estimate remains stationary?